# Get windows current loggedin user

Tags: angularjs, windows, google-chrome

What is the simplest way to get the windows current logged-in username in client side running on chrome browser?
I need a short JS code example that retrieve only the username.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery SPGetCurrentUser() to get the current logged in username in sharepoint 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244679/jquery-spgetcurrentuser-to-get-the-current-logged-in-username-in-sharepoint-20)

Comment: This might help you https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/can-your-windows-or-linux-username-be-exposed-to-websites

Comment: you can set the session variable . `$window.sessionStorage["username"]`